# Passing object reference variables

Tags: java

This is from the famous SCJP Java book.My question is how does dim get the value of 11 here.

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
class ReferenceTest {
    public static void main (String [] args) {
        Dimension d = new Dimension(5,10);
        ReferenceTest rt = new ReferenceTest();
        System.out.println("Before modify() d.height = "+ d.height);
        rt.modify(d);
        System.out.println("After modify() d.height = "+ d.height);
    }
    void modify(Dimension dim) {
        dim.height = dim.height + 1;
        System.out.println("dim = " + dim.height);
    }
}
```

When we run this class, we can see that the `modify()` method was indeed able to modify the original (and only) Dimension object created on line 4.

```
C:\Java Projects\Reference>java ReferenceTest
Before modify() d.height = 10
dim = 11
After modify() d.height = 11
```

Notice when the Dimension object on line 4 is passed to the modify() method, any changes to the object that occur inside the method are being made to the object whose reference was passed. In the preceding example, reference variables d and dim both point to the same object.

Comment: Because 10 + 1 = 11?

Comment: But we never passed the value of 10 to the variable  'Dim'!

Comment: Yes, you did. It comes from the reference to the `Dimension` object `d` that is passed into the `modify` method. You assign `10` to that object's field when you create it using `new Dimension(5,10)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is how does dim get the value of 11 here

`dim` **doesn't**. `dim.height` does. When the code passes `dim` into the method, the value passed in is a reference to an object. The method then modifies the state of that object (which doesn't modify the *reference* at all), and so the calling code sees the updated state.

This code:

```
Dimension d = new Dimension(5, 10);
```

Produces something like this in memory:

```
+-------------+
|      d      |
+-------------+     +--------------------+
| (reference) |---->| Dimension instance |
+-------------+     +--------------------+
                    | width: 5           |
                    | height: 10         |
                    +--------------------+
```

The variable holds a value that refers to the object *elsewhere* in memory. You can copy that value (called an *object reference*), for instance by passing it into a method, but it still refers to the same object.

So when we pass that into `modify`, during the call to `modify`, we have:

```
+-------------+
|      d      |
+-------------+
| (reference) |--+
+-------------+  |
                 |  +--------------------+
                 +->| Dimension instance |
                 |  +--------------------+
                 |  | width: 5           |
                 |  | height: 10         |
                 |  +--------------------+
+-------------+  |
|     dim     |  |
+-------------+  |
| (reference) |--+
+-------------+
```

Now, `d` and `dim` each have a copy of the value that tells the JVM where the object is in memory.

This is fundamental to how objects work: The value held by variables, data members, and arguments is a *reference* to the object, not a copy of it. It's like a number the JVM can use to look up the object elsewhere in memory.

Primitives are actually held inside the variable/data member/argument:

```
int n = 10;
```

Gives us:

```
+----+
| n  |
+----+
| 10 |
+----+
```

...but variables/data members/arguments don't hold objects, they hold a value that *refers to* an object.

Comment: But the variable dim is not declared anywhere ?

Comment: @user4203815: `dim` is an argument (which is very much like a variable), `d` is the variable. But it doesn't matter.